# What's the American version of "fellow member"?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english

**Fellow member** means:

> Someone who is a member of the same organization or society as you.

[*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/fellow-member)

The dictionary states that it means that in *British*, so what is its exact synonym in American English?

Also, I have found this paragraph outside the site [*Vocabulary*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fellow%20member):

> A male person who is a **fellow member** (of a fraternity or religion or other group) cabalist. a member of a cabal. charter member. one of the original members when an organization was founded.
>
> [image: A screenshot of the above questionable definition]

Is that considered as another meaning of **fellow member**? Since I didn't find it inside the site when I clicked on it, I'm asking about its validity and existence.

Comment: A fellow member just means a member in the same organization as myself. I belong to a club, so I say at a meeting: "I am sure my fellow members will agree that A, B and C is x, y and z". It is not British per se at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merriam-Webster *uses* that phrase, "fellow member" to define [the more obscure word *comember*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comember). Google [ngram shows it being used to a fairly similar extent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28fellow%20member%3Aeng_us_2012%29%2C%28fellow%20member%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%2Ccomember&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28fellow%20member%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28fellow%20member%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomember%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(fellow%20member%3Aeng_us_2012)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(fellow%20member%3Aeng_gb_2012)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomember%3B%2Cc0) on both sides of the Atlantic (and that people hardly use *comember* at all).

Thus, I think it's fair to say that it is **not a predominately British phrase**.

The second quotation is not of a definition of *fellow member*. It is part of a list of definitions, and goodness knows where Google got it from, and *fellow member* is part of the definition of something else. It is then followed by definitions of *cabalist* and *charter member*, so we can perhaps assume that whatever it defines comes before those terms in an alphabetical list of terms related to membership.

Comment: "I think it's fair to say that it is not a predominately British phrase." - Agreed.

Comment: Thank you! So, does it have only one meaning (_i.e._ it can't possibly mean the second quoted definition)?

Comment: @TasneemZH As an American I wouldn't take *fellow member* as a set phrase meaning anything; at the very least, it seems strange to restrict the term to males. I read it as simply the attribute pair of *fellow* and *member*, with all their various meanings. A member of a cabal or conspiracy might be a *fellow traveler*, although that term originated specifically to refer to people who were sympathizers but not actually members. Someone who is a member of an organization at its founding would be a *founding member* (or *founding father*, etc.) or *charter member* or *original member*.

Comment: @TasneemZH I don't know where you got the second quote. It appears to be several definitions, and I don't find it at the link.

Comment: @SamBC _ I have added how I found it. And as I have mentioned in my question, it is strangely not inside the site.

Comment: @choster _ Noted! And thank you for sharing that.

Comment: @TasneemZH Well, I don't know where it came from, but that text is obviously the *middle* of a paragraph, or at least sentence. "Fellow member" is being used as part of a definition, there. It is in a list of definitions, followed by the definition of *cabalist* and of *charter member*. It is not a definition of *fellow member* at all.